# Tweepy Bot Crashes After Duplicates

Tags: heroku, twitter, crash, bots, tweepy

I have a question about running my Twitter bot 24/7, and I already have it uploaded to Heroku. The code works great.

However, the dynos will fall asleep after 30 minutes of non-use. This is great, however, my code is programming to tweet the same thing once a day.

In order to keep the dynos alive, the code has to be run every 30 minutes. The tweet, however, is the same thing once a day.

Is there a way to keep the Twitter code running when receiving a duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to bypass the limit, but that is not possible. if you keep running that service all day your free hours will expire.

> Verified accounts come with a monthly pool of 1000 Free dyno hours; unverified >accounts receive 550. When a Free dyno is active, it draws from the pool; your free >apps can run as long as there are dyno hours left in your monthly pool.

instead, better to upgrade the Heroku to the premium version.